# Map IP addresses to ports on switch? HP 2530-24G J9776A

Tags: ip, hp, switch, address

We are trying to inventory incoming stock (used Mac computers) and are using `Deploystudio` and a special script.

One of the conditions of the script and the database system is that each incoming machine has to receive a specific IP address from the switch's port for the purpose of being logged in the database.

E.g `port 1 =192.168.1.10`, `Port 2 = 192.168.1.20`... whichever device connects to these will **ALWAYS** get one of these example addresses.

The switch in question is a `HP 2530-24G J9776A`.

I searched high and low on Google and this appears only to be a managed `Layer-2` switch.

The [HP Quick Specs Document](https://www.hpe.com/h20195/v2/getpdf.aspx/c04111414.pdf?ver=1) makes a passing reference to `Layer 3` as a "*Class of Service*" feature and benefit.

If this is a `layer-2` only switch and cares only about `MAC address` and thus nothing higher up the stack (IP addresses etc...).

Are there any workarounds for the issue?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Why would you want this to work in this manner?

Comment: so would a DHCP reservation not work? Layer 2 devices dont see IP addresses. They route based on MAC (layer 2). Do you not understand the OSI model or how routers/swtiches work?

Comment: All people seem to need data processing! Yes, I do understand the OSI model and how routers and switches operate. I alluded to that in my original question.

Comment: This is something my managers wants - the linking of IP addresses to physical ports on a switch. I've already expressed my doubts to him as the switch (appears at least) to be Layer 2 only. If anybody has experience of HP switches and can say if this is not possible, and thus confirm, my doubts I would be glad. Thanks again.

Comment: With a 2530 alone this is not possible. Maybe a switch with built-in DHCP server can manage - but I doubt it.

Comment: Hi Zac67, thanks for letting me know. Your insight on the topic means a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The switch port doesn't hand out IP addresses. The DHCP server does.

Alternatively

1. Put the port in question in a separate VLAN. Set up the DHCP scope for that VLAN with a single address and a very short lease time. Route the VLAN into you network.
2. Create/change a DHCP reservation on the fly for the MAC address of the machine before you plug it in.
3. Script the machine to statically use the IP address you require.
4. Make the script smarter so it detects the correct IP address from the DHCP log.

Comment: OK, thanks for that. I suspected that several individual VLANs would be possible workaround.  Was just afraid of managing the programming of it! Do you if know NetInstall (the technology DeployStudio run on) works well with multiple VLANs/broadcast domains?

Comment: I've got no idea about NetInstall or DeployStudio. However, if they're able to use a routed link or you can directly attach the VLAN/subnet to the server(?), it'll work.